# Run Main Class in Spring In Action 3

Tags: spring, maven, program-entry-point

I imported `Spring In Action 3`. How do I have to modify the `pom.xml` to `run a Main class` instead of or additional to the Junit test? I added the following plugin to the parent pom.xml, but this will not be executed.

> ```
>       <plugin>
>             <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
>             <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
>             <version>1.2.1</version>
>             <executions>
>                 <execution>
>                     <goals>
>                         <goal>java</goal>
>                     </goals>
>                 </execution>
>             </executions>
>             <configuration>
>                 <mainClass>com.springinaction.knights.KnightMain</mainClass>
>             </configuration>
>         </plugin>
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the execution of the plugin to the `test` phase, for example

```
        <executions>
           <execution>
              <id>run-class-as-part-of-tests</id>
              <phase>test</phase>
              <goals>
                 <goal>java</goal>
              </goals>
           </execution>
        </executions>
```

This **won't** stop running the unit tests, as the maven-surefire-plugin (which runs the tests) is bound to the test phase too. So if you want to skip the tests, you need to set the property `skip` to true of the maven-surefire-plugin (check the documentation [here](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html))

Comment: Now the Main will be executed, but I receive a `ClassDefNotFoundException`. Where do I have to set the classpath?

Comment: I found the reason. The plugin has to be inserted into `child-pom` and not into parent-pom.

@Augusto, thanks for your help

Comment: Thanks Augusto, this was the answer (phase test) I was looking for! (Sorry, I'm still not able to vote, but I will do it as soon as possible)